# Como carregar arquivo css no Django?

Tags: css, aplicação-web, django

Comecei a estudar django e estou com um problema, o Django não consegue carregar o CSS (Obs: Já foi dei CTRL+F5 e ainda assim não carrega o CSS)

Informações que podem ser uteis:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

pasta já criada

dentro dessa pasta contem o css/styles.css
,meu codigo no html está assim

já carreguei o {% load static %}

Quando eu exibo o codigo fonte da pagina ela se encontra assim:

"< link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css" />"

Comment: Pela falta de detalhes da sua pergunta tenho certeza que vc não leu a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.0/howto/static-files/), se puder recomedar algo, recomendo que além de lê-la, faça o tutorial da própria.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a seguinte sintaxe nas suas templates:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'caminho/para/o/seu/arquivo.css' %}/>
```

Serve para qualquer arquivo dentro do diretório `/static`.

Comment: Resolvido, valeu